# In UK, are new smart energy meters secure?

Tags: measurements, electrical, gas

I have read [this newspaper article](https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2016/dec/29/smart-electricity-meters-dangerously-insecure-hackers) about insecurities in smart meters.

Some quotes from the piece:

> To communicate with the utility company, most smart meters use GSM, the 2G mobile standard. That has a fairly well-known weakness whereby an attacker with a fake mobile tower can cause devices to “hand over” to the fake version from the real tower, simply by providing a strong signal. In GSM, devices have to authenticate with towers, but not the other way round, allowing the fake mast to send its own commands to the meter.

> Worse still ... all the meters from one utility used the same hardcoded credentials. “If an attacker gains access to one meter, it gains access to them all. It is the one key to rule them all.”

> Other weak security decisions made by vendors include:

> • Encryption keys derived from short (often just six-character) device names.

> • Pairing standards with no authentication required, allowing an attacker to simply ask the smart meter to join the network and receive keys in return.
> • Hardcoded credentials, allowing administrator access with passwords as simple and guessable as the vendor’s name.

> • Code simplified to work on low-power devices skipping important checks, allowing nothing more than a long communication to crash the device.

The article is quite old (December 2016), but I am unable to verify if the weaknesses have been overcome. All I can find are claims that they are “secure and encrypted”, with no technical details.

Can anyone add any further details of the current state of smart meter security? Please note I am only interested in the UK market.

### Edit I have heard back from the energy company

I asked specifically for technical details, hoping for something that could be verified. I may not have understood it all, but there are nice people here who would gladly help.

The answer I received was only a link to an advertising page, and was not useful at all. I interpret it as "I don't know".

Comment: Why not ask the Power Companies that use those meters? They should be able to give you a clear answer.

Comment: [Smart meter warning: Cyber experts warn devices could leave you vulnerable to burglars](https://www.express.co.uk/news/uk/1661408/smart-meter-warning-cyber-experts-devices-energy-gap-burglaries-crime)  *There have currently been no hackings involving [UK] smart meter data reported.*  The more data that is out there, the greater chance someone will hack it.

Comment: @SolarMike, of course I am pursuing that route, but without confidence. What makes you think a power company can provide verifiable technical details? I expect them just to repeat the advertising statements from the meter manufacturer.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat, I was looking for reassurance that they were safe. You have supplied the opposite - thanks! Now I feel justified in refusing to 'upgrade'.

Comment: Why are you assuming that power companies are not technically competent? based on your "What makes you think a power company can provide verifiable technical details? I expect them just to repeat the advertising statements from the meter manufacturer"

Comment: @SolarMike. I once had a stream of alerts from NoScript while using my bank's web site. Their help desk could answer banking questions, but not IT ones. I had to change banks. I will update this question whenever I hear back from my power company.

Comment: So it sounds like you take your car to your butcher for a service. Expecting the bank to be able to deal with IT / web issues is a bit much...

Comment: Cyber threats evolve.  Holes are found, exploited and eventually plugged.   Put a mobile resource in the area, figure out how to fake out the existing comms system, hack the protocol, figure out the data format, to do what?  There are more profitable endevours than burgulary for the hacker that can do that.

Comment: @SolarMike I don't know WHO wrote the bank's web site, no more than I know who makes the smart meters I have been offered. Where do you recommend that I direct my queries?

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat Please put your comments into an answer. The Express link seems the nearest  thing to an answer to my post.

Comment: My GSM-technology meter has just had the transceiver replaced with a mesh  technology transceiver. It's an (internal) plug in module. I don't know if it's "more" secure, but the security problems have certainly been addressed -- even if only changed to different problems.